# Application of the reflection theorem in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

In a proof that a certain theory $T$ in conservative over $\textsf{ZFC}$, the author makes the following step:

(Here $\Delta$ is a finite set of formulas such that $\textsf{ZFC}\vdash\Delta$.)

Suppose that $\Delta\not\vdash\psi$. Then, by the Levy-Montague reflection theorem, there is some ordinal $\lambda$ such that $(V_{\lambda},\in)\vDash\neg\psi$.

Why does this follow? I understand that we can reflect the set $\Delta\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ at some level of the hierarchy. But can we really get a model $(V_{\lambda},\in)$ satisfying $\Delta\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ just from the assumption that there exists *some* model of $\Delta\cup\{\neg\psi\}$?

Comment: What author? What source?

Comment: Do you - by any chance - mean $\Delta \vdash \neg \psi$ instead? Otherwise this is just false (in general).

Comment: Here is a blind guess assuming the statement is meant to be true: if $\Delta$ is a large enough finite subset of ZFC that does not imply $\psi$, then there is an ordinal $\lambda$ in a model $V\models\Delta$ such that $V_\lambda\models\neg\psi$.